# Does asserting the existence of large cardinals allow one to prove the existence of new subsets of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

ZFC proves the existence of certain subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose ZFC is consistent, and we adjoin a large cardinal axiom to ZFC, obtaining ZFC'. Assume ZFC' is also consistent. It it possible to prove the existence of new subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ using ZFC'?

Comment: Yes. Definitely. (Of course, what precisely depends on the specific axiom being added.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be more precise to say that "ZFC + large cardinals" proves more *statements* positing the existence of sets of reals with certain *logical properties* (*e.g.* it proves more $\Sigma^2_1$ statements) than to say that it proves the existence of new subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. That being said, assuming the existence of large cardinals certainly does allow you to prove more along these lines, even about single reals.

For example, if there is a measurable cardinal then $0^\sharp$ exists, *i.e.* there is a unique real $x$ that computes the set of sentences true in Goedel's constructible universe $L$ (and a bit more.)  The statement $x = 0^\sharp$ is absolute between models of set theory containing a given real $x$ and having the same ordinals, so $0^\sharp$ is a fairly robust notion.
However, $0^\sharp$ is not contained in the inner model $L$ (which satisfies ZFC) so one cannot prove the statement "$0^\sharp$ exists" in ZFC alone.

If you want to consider *sets* of reals rather than single reals, then you could consider the statement "$\mathbb{R}^\sharp$ exists", which is stronger but still follows from the existence of a measurable cardinal.  Some important but technical $\Sigma^2_1$ statements that are even stronger than this in terms of consistency strength are iterability statements like "there exists an iteration strategy for a premouse with a superstrong cardinal."

Comment: Or you could even prove that $\forall A\exists A^\#$ from a supercompact. That's pretty nifty.

Comment: @Asaf or even from the Proper Forcing Axiom, which is perhaps niftier.

Comment: But PFA is probably equiconsistent with a supercompact... what's the deal with that, did they finish the proof yet? :-)

Comment: @Asaf Just give me a few more days...or decades

Comment: Well, PFA proves that $\omega_2$ is thinly ineffable. So you just need to find that canonical inner model for supercompactness and you're practically halfway through the proof! (The other half being that $\omega_2$ is supercompact in such inner model, of course...) :-)

Comment: @Asaf Yep, halfway there---I'll let you take it from here :)  (For some reason I'm not being notified of comments today...weird.)